# How to get the values of all input fields jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have a program where it starts off with one input field, and if you press the plus button it adds new input field. I also have it so it gives the new input field a different id. I would prefer it so when i press calculate, it saves the values of all the input fields data into an array. I have tried using a for loop with .val(), but that didnt work.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<!-- ************where the input fields are*******-->
<div id="append">
 <p style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:0px;">
        <input type='text' class='minutes' id="minute1"/>
        <input type='text' class='vidseconds' id="second1"/>
 </p>
 <div id="plusnminus">
        <button id="plus">+</button>
        <button id="minus">-</button>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- when this is pressed i want it to save the input fields data-->
<p id="calculate">Calculate</p>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
//JavaScript

$(document).ready(function(){
 var mins = [];
 //where it add the new input field
 var idnum = 1;
 $("#plus").click(function(){
  idnum+=1;
  var input = "<p><input type='text' class='minutes' id='minute"+idnum+"' /><input type='text' class='vidseconds'            id='second"+idnum+"'/></p>";
  $(input).appendTo("#append");
 });
     
 // to remove an input field
 $("#minus").click(function(){
  if(idnum >= 2){
   $("#minute" + idnum+ ", #second" + idnum).remove();
   idnum-=1;
  }
 });
     
    // i want it to put all of the data from the input fields in an array in that click function
 $("#calculate").click(function(){
       
 });     
});
```

```css
/*StyleSheet */

#append {
 display: inline-block;
}
#plusnminus {
 display: inline-block;
}
button {
 border-style: none;
 background-color: #C0C0C0;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
}
```

Everything is inline because i'm trying to keep it a single file. I have placed comments however for readability.

Comment: How did you try to do it with the array? Maybe you had a simple typo.

Comment: Check this link:-https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: Petras99: dynamically created elements can't simply access with normal jquery. Try to use 'on' function in jquery. It can couple functionalities to dynamically created elements.

Comment: The code was: `var mins = [];      for(var x = 0; x < idnum; x++){mins[x] = $("#minutes" + x+1).val() } @epascarrello

Comment: @JTheDev alright i'll look at the documentation for 'on' and see how it works. I'll tell you if i get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.map()`, selectors `#append input[id^=minute]`, `#append input[id^second]` to get all `input` elements that are descendants of `#append` element; return an array containing two arrays of values, utilize destructuring assignment to set variable identifiers; for example, `minutes`, `seconds`, for arrays corresponding to `.value` of element where `id` begins with `"minute"` or `"second"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mins = [];

  //where it add the new input field
  var idnum = 1;
  $("#plus").click(function() {
    idnum += 1;

    var input = "<p><input type='text' class='minutes' id='minute" 
                + idnum 
                + "' /><input type='text' class='vidseconds' id='second" 
                + idnum 
                + "'/></p>";
    $(input).appendTo("#append");
  });

  // to remove an input field
  $("#minus").click(function() {
    if (idnum >= 2) {
      $("#minute" + idnum + ", #second" + idnum).remove();
      idnum -= 1;
    }
  });

  // i want it to put all of the data 
  // from the input fields in an array 
  // in that click function
  $("#calculate").click(function() {
    var [minutes, seconds] = $.map([$("#append input[id^=minute]")
                             , $("#append input[id^=second]")]
      , function(el) {
      return [$.map(el, function(elem) {
        return elem.value;
      })]
    });
    // do stuff with `minutes`, `seconds` variables
    console.log("minutes:", minutes, "seconds:", seconds);
  });
});
```

```css
#append {
  display: inline-block;
}
#plusnminus {
  display: inline-block;
}
button {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- ************where the input fields are*******-->
  <div id="append">
    <p style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:0px;">
      <input type='text' class='minutes' id="minute1" />
      <input type='text' class='vidseconds' id="second1" />
    </p>

    <div id="plusnminus">
      <button id="plus">+</button>
      <button id="minus">-</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- when this is pressed i want it to save the input fields data-->
  <p id="calculate">Calculate</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can alternatively substitute `Array.from()` for `$.map()`

```
var [minutes, seconds] = Array.from([$("#append input[id^=minute]")
                                   , $("#append input[id^=second]")]
                         , function(el) {
                             return Array.from(el, function(elem) {
                               return elem.value;
                             });
                         });
```

Comment: How would i go about seeing the value of the data placed in the array of objects?

Comment: @Petras99 `inputs[/* index of element in array */]["minutes"]` or `inputs[/* index of element in array */]["vidseconds"]`. You can also set the property name to another identifier. Or, instead of returning an object, return only `.value` of element. Are you trying to only include `input` elements where `id` begins with `minute`? What is expected result?

Comment: @Petras99 Using selector to match only `input` elements where `id` begings with `"minute" return `.value` of element to array `var inputs = $.map($("#append input[id^=minute]"), function(el) {
  return el.value
});`

Comment: @Petras99 Or, are you trying to add all the values of the `input` elements?

Comment: My expected result is of the values that have the id of `"minute" + idnum` which i believe i will be able to do with your code, and a for loop

Comment: @Petras99 Do you mean the `.value` of all `input` elements where the `id` begins with `"minute"`?

Comment: yes, my goal is to get the data that is inputted into the fields, i will need both the field id's that start with `"minute"` and the id's that start with `second`, however i will need them in seperate arrays. I apologize if i am not answering your questions correctly.

Comment: Thank you!!! This works exactly how i need it to. Again i apologize if i was being confusing, or not answering your questions correctly. But thank you again, this work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your input fields in a form, you can use [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to serialize the whole form at once.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#my-button').on('click', function() {
    var values = $('#my-form').serializeArray();
    console.log(values);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="input1" value="first field"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input2" value="second field"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="input3" value="third field"><br/>
</form>

<button id="my-button">Get All Values</button>
```